# FluentAssertions Should().BeOfType() or derived type?

Tags: fluent-assertions

I have the following situation:

```
class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}
```

I want to assert that variables of typeof(B) are assignable to typeof(A) variables. How to do that with fluent assertions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you can use `BeAssignableTo<T>` for this:

```cs
var b = new B();
        
b.Should().BeAssignableTo<A>();
```

This is almost your own sentence you have written. :)